# Мне есть(,) что сказать

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология

***Мне есть(,) что сказать***. Нужна ли здесь запятая? Может быть, ***есть что сказать*** является неразложимым словосочетанием, запятая внутри которого не ставится?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. Приведу отрывок из справочника Розенталя:

> Запятая не ставится внутри выражений типа *есть чем заняться*, *есть над чем поработать*, *было о чём подумать*, *найду куда обратиться*, *не нахожу что сказать*, *осталось на что жить*, состоящих из глагола *быть* или *найти* (*найтись*), *остаться* и вопросительно-относительного местоимения или наречия (кто, что, где, куда, когда и т. д.) и неопределенной формы другого глагола: Тебе есть в мире что забыть (Л.); Бранить есть кому, кормить — некому (Даль); Есть чему и нравиться (Пис.); И нашу интеллигенцию есть за что любить, есть за что уважать (М.Г.); Есть над чем задуматься; Нашли чем удивить; Не нашёлся что сказать; У нас будет чем козырнуть; Нашла где модничать; Есть когда с тобой болтать!; Было отчего приуныть; Друзьям есть о чём поговорить; Ребятам было где проводить свободное время; Нам было в чём упрекнуть его.