# "Чтобы потом хотя бы было(,) что спасать"

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в этой фразе?

> чтобы потом хотя бы было(,) что спасать

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427233/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Answer (score 0):

*чтобы потом хотя бы было что спасать*

Предложение в целом неграмотно составлено, потому что нет согласования по времени (в будущем времени ("потом") не может быть прошедшего времени ("было")).
Тут требуется или сослагательное наклонение глагола "быть" с будущим временем: **было бы** что спасать **потом**, когда всё это это **закончится**;
или одно время: чтобы **потом** хотя бы что-нибудь **спасти**.

Но если закрыть глаза на несогласованность, то запятая перед "что" не нужна. Потому что слово "что" является здесь не союзом (перед которым обычно ставится запятая), а синонимом местоимения (**что-то** спасаемое):
Чтобы потом хотя бы было **что-то** для спасения.

Comment: Никакой неграмотности - фраза совершенно правильная. Таких "рассогласований во времени" в русском языке пруд пруди. "Хотя бы" отсюда не выбросишь, а два "бы" подряд (хотя бы было бы) - вот это было бы неграмотным.