# Есть(,) во что верить. Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Есть(,) во что верить.

Нужна ли запятая?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Мне есть(,) что сказать](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427233/%d0%9c%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: Пользуйтесь опцией **Поиск**.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, запятая не нужна.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146, пункт 7.

Внутри выражений типа *есть чем заняться*, *есть над чем поработать*, *было о чём подумать*, *найду куда обратиться*, *не нахожу что сказать*, *осталось на что жить*, состоящих из глагола *быть*, или *найти (найтись)*, или *остаться* и вопросительно-относительного местоимения либо наречия (кто, что, где, куда, когда и т. д.) и неопределенной формы другого глагола, запятая не ставится.